# get month,date and year from given date

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get the month and date from the given date.I get server time  . `date="Wed Jul 26 2017 11:39:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"`; I want to get  mm/dd/yyyy from the given date

```
        var xmlHttp;
    function srvTime(){
    try {
        //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (err1) {
        //IE
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch (err2) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch (eerr3) {
                //AJAX not supported, use CPU time.
                alert("AJAX not supported");
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open('HEAD',window.location.href.toString(),false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    xmlHttp.send('');
    return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
    }
    var st = srvTime();
    var date = new Date(st);  
    console.log(date); //Wed Jul 26 2017 11:39:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: I want to get month number as 07

Comment: You should make some effort to write your own code. There are thousands of duplicate questions here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getDate()`, `getMonth()` and `getFullYear()`.
Add 1 to month as Javascript return months as 0 for January, 1 for February, etc.

```js
var date = new Date();

var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();

console.log('Day:' + day);
console.log('Month:' + month);
console.log('Year:' + year);

if(day < 10){
    day='0'+day;
} 
if(month<10){
    month='0'+month;
} 
var today = month+'/'+day+'/'+year;
console.log('Date:' + today);
```

Comment: You should not answer questions that are obvious duplicates, particularly where the OP has not made any attempt to write their own code. This question has been asked many, many times before. Searching on [*javascript format date*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+format+date) returns 22,000 results just here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods:

```
var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
var mm = date.getMonth();
var dd = date.getDay();
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to write custom code, something like this.

```
  function formatDate(date) {
      var day = date.getDate();
      var month = date.getMonth();
      var year = date.getFullYear();

      return (month+1) + '/' + day + '/' + year;
    }

    console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```